# phpseclib-SSH2 stream results from command?

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib to ssh into a remote device and download files.
This works and when it completes it shows a list of files it has downloaded.

However I'd like it to show each filename as it's downloaded.

The code I'm using is:

```
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.0.1');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    } 
    function output($str) {
        echo "$str";
    }


    $cmd = "getfiles";
    $res = $ssh->exec($cmd, "output");
```

If I use putty and SSH into the remote device and then run `getfiles` it will show each filename on a new line as it is handled.

phpseclib seems to just show the final result, not the live progress.

Is there anyway to make it show the live progress ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tom, I can't quite tell from your question: are you using [this phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/) for the ssh-related code? Or are you using [this Net_SSH2](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_SSH2)? Or something else?

Comment: @summea I'm using phpseclib. I've now got this working by adding a flush to the output function.

Comment: Nice to hear that it's working! Would it be possible to post your findings as an answer to your question if you have time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this working by updating the output function as follows.

```
function output($str) {
    flush();  ob_flush();
    echo "$str<br>";
}
```

Now the output is shown on a new line.